# R convert character list to matrices with empty values

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, dataset, cbind

in R, I have a character list:

```
> column_list
> "C", "F", "G", "M", "O", "Y", "Z"
> typeof(column_list)
> "character"
```

I wish to populate each item in this list with 0s on a defined length N so that it is a matrix that looks like this:

```
C   F   G   M   O   Y   Z
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
... n times
```

I then want to combine this matrix (using cbind?) to another matrix and order it alphabetically.

```
A    B    D   E   H    I ...
.1  .2   .1  .5  .1   .1
 0  .2   .3   0   0   .2
.1   0   .1  .1   0   .3
...
```

such that my new matrix looks like this

```
 A   B   C    D   E   F    G    H    I ...
.1  .2   0   .1  .5   0    0   .1   .1
 0  .2   0   .3   0   0    0    0   .2
.1   0   0   .1  .1   0    0    0   .3
 ...
```

How can I do these two steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following steps as guidance to achieve your code or make a function.

In the fist step use `matrix()` in conjuction with an additional parameter `NROW` and the length of the character vector `column_list` to define the number of rows and columns of your zero-matrix. The function take advantage of the *recycling property* and populated the matrix elements with zeros.

The second step is combine, as you say, the zero matrix (X) with another (Y) matrix with `cbind` to have the Z matrix . **The following assumptions must be consider**: *Y has the same number of rows and the columns of Y has different names (to properly identify the procedence).* Then, you just reorder your matrix with square parenthesis and the function `order()` based on the column names of the new matrix (Z).

```
# STEP 1: create the matrix based on a character vector (ncol) and 
# a NROW parameter (nrow) and populate values with 0
column_list <- c("C", "F", "G", "M", "O", "Y", "Z")
NROW <- 10
X <- matrix(0, nrow = NROW, ncol = length(column_list))
colnames(X) <- column_list

# STEP 2: Given another matrix Y, assume that have same number of rows and
# different column names. Bind both matrices by column and order the column
# based on the name of these (alphabetically)
Y <- matrix(1, nrow = 10, ncol = 2)   # create another matrix 
colnames(Y) <- c("D", "L")            # with colnames D and L

Z <- cbind(X, Y)                      # combine
Z <- Z[, order(colnames(Z))]          # order based on the column names
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! It's exactly what I was looking for, just made a few adjustments specific to my dataset. Thanks for the line by line code comments as well, helped me understand what each line was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the new data frame, then bind, then reorder the columns. To do this, you use the `sort()` function on the vector of column names and assign the output to a vector. Then you can subset your dataframe by the defined column vector to reorder the columns

```
missing_letters <- data.frame(                        
    C = rep(0, 3), # N = 3 in this example                
    F = rep(0, 3),                                        
    G = rep(0, 3),                                        
    M = rep(0, 3),                                        
    O = rep(0, 3),                                        
    Y = rep(0, 3),                                        
    Z = rep(0, 3)                                         
)                                                     

your_letters <- data.frame(                           
    A = c(.1, 0, .1),                                     
    B = c(.2, .2, 0),                                     
    D = c(.1, .3, .1),                                    
    E = c(.5, 0, .1),                                     
    H = c(.1, 0, 0),                                      
    I = c(.1, .2, .3)                                     
)                                                     

binded_letters <- cbind(your_letters, missing_letters)

alphabetical_order <- sort(colnames(binded_letters))  

final_data <- binded_letters[, alphabetical_order]    

final_data                                            
#>     A   B C   D   E F G   H   I M O Y Z
#> 1 0.1 0.2 0 0.1 0.5 0 0 0.1 0.1 0 0 0 0
#> 2 0.0 0.2 0 0.3 0.0 0 0 0.0 0.2 0 0 0 0
#> 3 0.1 0.0 0 0.1 0.1 0 0 0.0 0.3 0 0 0 0
```